# NestJS remove console warning for circular dependency

Tags: warnings, circular-dependency, nestjs

is there a way to remove all the circular dependencies warnings (from typeorm)  in the console? everything is working fine but i have like 50+ pages of warning in the console log before the start up NestJs logs